# Remove a particular jar from plugin on creation of war in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, dependency-management

I'm using dynamic-jasper:0.6 with my Grails 2.2.4 application, the plugin is currently importing an older version of mysql-connector **mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar** which in some cases is conflicting with my current connector and creating some problem. I'd like to keep on using the plugin without modifying it but also exclude the particular jar file and only include the library I need. Is there any way to achieve this?

I tried excluding the file from _Events.groovy but it didn't work here is my code

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")

target(main: "The description of the script goes here!") {
    eventCreateWarStart = { name, stagingDir ->
    ant.delete(dir:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/", includes: "mysql-connector*.jar", verbose: true)
}
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add in your `scripts/_Events.groovy`:

```
eventCreateWarStart = { name, stagingDir ->
    ant.delete(dir:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/", includes: "xercesImpl*.jar", verbose: true)
}
```

Above example is of course for `xerces`, just change the `includes:` mask to your liking. In case you already have a closure `eventCreateWarStart`, only add the `ant.delete` part.

Yet in the case of the mysql-connector, which most likely is referenced as `runtime` from your current project, you might as well try to prevent it from bleeding in from the plugin with an exclude, like (`BuildConfig.groovy` for e.g. an entry in the `plugins` section):

```
compile(":vaadin:7.3.9") { excludes 'xercesImpl' }
```

See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies for `Excluding specific transitive dependencies`

Comment: Actually I already tried that here is my _Events.groovy, didn't work

includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")

target(main: "The description of the script goes here!") {
    // TODO: Implement script here
    eventCreateWarStart = { name, stagingDir ->
        ant.delete(dir:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/", includes: "mysql-connector*.jar", verbose: true)
    }
}

setDefaultTarget(main)

Comment: so you are _writing_ a plugin yourself and you don't want to have that exported? in that case it should work alot easier, if you just `exclude` the artifact in your BuildConfig?

Comment: No I'm trying to remove the jar from preexisting plugin. I've updated my question with my code of _Events.groovy.

Comment: _Events is no script as the others.  just put above code in there.  without the init stuff and main etc.  or at least this syntax is way to complicated for my taste or a relict from an old grails version maybe?

Comment: Guess using the default code generated by IDE was a bad Idea. just putting it plainly worked thanks